set audio inside list view builder audio play automatically when I scroll
I use just audio package and set audio inside listview.builder and I click first button the audio is play but when I scroll the list the audio automatically play and is not playing correct index by index how to fix it ?
class verselist_screen extends StatefulWidget {
  final qurandata1;
  final qurandata2;
  final qurandata3;
  verselist_screen({
    this.qurandata1,
    this.qurandata2,
    this.qurandata3,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<verselist_screen> createState() => _verselist_screenState();
}

class _verselist_screenState extends State<verselist_screen> {
  verselist_screen_modal vsm = Get.put(verselist_screen_modal());
  AudioPlayer player1 = AudioPlayer();
  AudioPlayer player2 = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player1.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        vsm.isCompleted.value = true;
        print('check isCompleted() value in stream = ${vsm.isCompleted.value}');
        vsm.isPlaying1.value = false;
        print('check isPlaying() value in stream = ${vsm.isPlaying1.value}');
      }
    });
    player1.setUrl(widget.qurandata3.audioFull["05"]!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player1.stop();
    player1.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appbar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * .3,
                  width: MediaQueryu.getScreenWidth(context) * .9,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: color1, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(verseimage1),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          myText(
                              widget.qurandata1.name
                              // qurandata1.name
                              ,
                              24.0,
                              Colors.white,
                              'PoppinsSemiBold'),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * 0.01,
                          ),
                          myText(
                              widget.qurandata1.englishNameTranslation
                              // qurandata1.englishNameTranslation
                              ,
                              15.0,
                              Colors.white,
                              'PoppinsSemiBold'),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * 0.01,
                          ),
                          // * 7 verses
                          myText(
                              "${widget.qurandata3.tempatTurun.toString()
                                  // qurandata1.revelationType.name.toString()
                                  }" +
                                  " *  ${widget.qurandata3.jumlahAyat
                                  // qurandata3.jumlahAyat
                                  }",
                              12.0,
                              Colors.white,
                              'PoppinsMedium'),
                          Obx(() {
                            return IconButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                debugPrint(
                                    'check isPlaying value in onPressed before ${vsm.isPlaying1.value = !vsm.isPlaying1.value}');
                                vsm.isPlaying1.value = !vsm.isPlaying1.value;
                                debugPrint(
                                    'check isPlaying value in onPressed after ${vsm.isPlaying1.value = !vsm.isPlaying1.value}');

                                if (vsm.isPlaying1.value) {
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'check 1st if isPlaying value = ${vsm.isPlaying1.value}');
                                  if (vsm.isCompleted.value) {
                                    debugPrint(
                                        'check 2st if isCompleted value before = ${vsm.isCompleted.value}');
                                    await player1.seek(Duration.zero);
                                    await player1.play();
                                    vsm.isCompleted.value = false;
                                    debugPrint(
                                        'check 2st if isCompleted value after = ${vsm.isCompleted.value}');
                                  } else {
                                    debugPrint(
                                        'check 2st else isCompleted value before = ${vsm.isCompleted.value}');
                                    await player1.play();
                                    debugPrint(
                                        'check 2st else isCompleted value after = ${vsm.isCompleted.value}');
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'check 1st else isPlaying value before = ${vsm.isPlaying1.value}');
                                  await player1.pause();
                                  debugPrint(
                                      'check 1st else isPlaying value after = ${vsm.isPlaying1.value}');
                                }
                              },
                              icon: vsm.isPlaying1.value
                                  ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                                  : Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                            );
                          })

                          // vsm.iconbutton()
                          // Obx(() {
                          //   return IconButton(
                          //     onPressed: () async {
                          //       debugPrint('check isPlaying value in onPressed before ${vsm.isPlaying.value = !vsm.isPlaying.value}');
                          //       vsm.isPlaying.value = !vsm.isPlaying.value;
                          //       debugPrint('check isPlaying value in onPressed after ${vsm.isPlaying.value = !vsm.isPlaying.value}');
                          //
                          //
                          //       if (vsm.isPlaying.value) {
                          //         debugPrint('check if block isPlaying value before ${vsm.isPlaying.value}');
                          //         await player.play();
                          //         debugPrint('check if block isPlaying value after ${vsm.isPlaying.value}');
                          //       } else {
                          //         debugPrint('check else block isPlaying value before ${vsm.isPlaying.value}');
                          //         await player.pause();
                          //         debugPrint('check else block isPlaying value after ${vsm.isPlaying.value}');
                          //       }
                          //     },
                          //     icon: vsm.isPlaying.value
                          //         ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                          //         : Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                          //   );
                          // })
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * 0.05,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.qurandata1.ayahs.length
                  // qurandata1.ayahs.length
                  ,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var quranaudio = widget.qurandata2.ayahs[index].audio;

                    player2.setUrl(quranaudio); // I set the audio here and when I scroll the audio automatically play and playing not according to index

                    print("print quran audio = ${quranaudio}");
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * 0.07,
                            width: MediaQueryu.getScreenWidth(context) * .9,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: color5,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 15,
                                      child: myText('${index + 1}', 14.0,
                                          Colors.white, 'PoppinsMedium'),
                                      backgroundColor: color1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  mySpacer(1),
                                  // SizedBox(width: MediaQueryu.getScreenWidth(context) * .5,),
                                  Image.asset(verseimage4),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: MediaQueryu.getScreenWidth(context) *
                                        0.02,
                                  ),

                                  Obx(() {
                                    return InkWell(
                                        onTap: () async {
                                          // vsm.selectedIndex = index;
                                          vsm.isPlaying2[index] = !vsm.isPlaying2[index];
                                          debugPrint(' print isPlaying2 result = ${vsm.isPlaying2[index].toString()}');
                                          if (
                                          vsm.isPlaying2[index]
                                          // vsm.isPlaying2.value
                                          ) {
                                            await player2.play();

                                          } else {
                                            await player2.pause();
                                          }
                                          // await player.setUrl(quranaudio);
                                          // await player.play();
                                          // playaudio(quranaudio);
                                        },
                                        child: vsm.isPlaying2[index]
                                        // vsm.isPlaying2.value
                                            ? Icon(
                                                    Icons.pause,
                                                    color: color1,
                                                  )
                                            : Icon(
                                          Icons.play_arrow,
                                          color: color1,
                                        )
                                        // vsm.isPlaying2.value
                                        //     ? index == vsm.selectedIndex ? Icon(Icons.pause,color: color1,) : Icon(Icons.play_arrow,color: color1)
                                        //     : index == vsm.selectedIndex ? Icon(Icons.play_arrow,color: color1) : Icon(Icons.pause,color: color1,) ,
                                        // Image.asset(verseimage2)
                                        );
                                  }),

                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: MediaQueryu.getScreenWidth(context) *
                                        0.02,
                                  ),
                                  Image.asset(verseimage3),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * 0.04,
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: myText(
                                  widget.qurandata2.ayahs[index].text
                                  // qurandata2.ayahs[index].text
                                  ,
                                  18.0,
                                  Colors.white,
                                  'AmiriBold')),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQueryu.getScreenHeight(context) * 0.02,
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: myText(
                                  widget.qurandata1.ayahs[index].text
                                  // qurandata1.ayahs[index].text
                                  ,
                                  16.0,
                                  Colors.white,
                                  'PoppinsRegular')),
                          Divider(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class verselist_screen_modal extends GetxController {

  RxBool isPlaying1 = false.obs;
  RxBool isCompleted = false.obs;
  // RxBool isPlaying2 = false.obs;
  var selectedIndex = 0;
  RxList<bool> isPlaying2 = List.generate(100, (index) => false).obs;

}



I try the to set the audio inside the inkwell but when I play the audio and pause it and I again play the audio audio was reset



Here are some key adjustments:

Avoid Setting the Audio URL Inside the itemBuilder: Setting the audio URL inside the itemBuilder will cause it to reset and possibly auto-play when the item is rebuilt during scrolling. Instead, set the audio URL only when the play button is pressed.
Control Audio Play/Pause Correctly: Ensure that each audio instance is managed independently and that only one audio plays at a time.
Maintain State for Each Item: Use a state management approach to maintain the playing state for each item in the list.


Here's the modified code with the necessary changes:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class VerselistScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final qurandata1;
  final qurandata2;
  final qurandata3;

  VerselistScreen({
    this.qurandata1,
    this.qurandata2,
    this.qurandata3,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<VerselistScreen> createState() => _VerselistScreenState();
}

class _VerselistScreenState extends State<VerselistScreen> {
  VerselistScreenModal vsm = Get.put(VerselistScreenModal());
  AudioPlayer player1 = AudioPlayer();
  AudioPlayer player2 = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player1.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        vsm.isCompleted.value = true;
        vsm.isPlaying1.value = false;
      }
    });
    player1.setUrl(widget.qurandata3.audioFull["05"]!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player1.stop();
    player1.dispose();
    player2.dispose();  // Dispose the second player too
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Verses List')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset('assets/verseimage1.png'),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(widget.qurandata1.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsSemiBold')),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                          ),
                          Text(widget.qurandata1.englishNameTranslation,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsSemiBold')),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                          ),
                          Text(
                              "${widget.qurandata3.tempatTurun} *  ${widget.qurandata3.jumlahAyat}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                          Obx(() {
                            return IconButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                vsm.isPlaying1.value = !vsm.isPlaying1.value;
                                if (vsm.isPlaying1.value) {
                                  if (vsm.isCompleted.value) {
                                    await player1.seek(Duration.zero);
                                    await player1.play();
                                    vsm.isCompleted.value = false;
                                  } else {
                                    await player1.play();
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  await player1.pause();
                                }
                              },
                              icon: vsm.isPlaying1.value
                                  ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                                  : Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                            );
                          })
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.qurandata1.ayahs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var quranaudio = widget.qurandata2.ayahs[index].audio;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 15,
                                      child: Text('${index + 1}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14.0,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium')),
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Spacer(),
                                  Image.asset('assets/verseimage4.png'),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                        0.02,
                                  ),
                                  Obx(() {
                                    return InkWell(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        if (vsm.isPlaying2[index]) {
                                          await player2.pause();
                                        } else {
                                          await player2.setUrl(quranaudio);
                                          await player2.play();
                                        }
                                        vsm.isPlaying2[index] = !vsm.isPlaying2[index];
                                        for (int i = 0; i < vsm.isPlaying2.length; i++) {
                                          if (i != index) vsm.isPlaying2[i] = false;
                                        }
                                      },
                                      child: vsm.isPlaying2[index]
                                          ? Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.blue)
                                          : Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.blue),
                                    );
                                  }),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                        0.02,
                                  ),
                                  Image.asset('assets/verseimage3.png'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Text(
                                  widget.qurandata2.ayahs[index].text,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'AmiriBold'))),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                          ),
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                  widget.qurandata1.ayahs[index].text,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular'))),
                          Divider(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerselistScreenModal extends GetxController {
  RxBool isPlaying1 = false.obs;
  RxBool isCompleted = false.obs;
  RxList<bool> isPlaying2 = List.generate(100, (index) => false).obs;
}

Hope it will help.

can you explain me logic you are using plz ?

For sure!
1- Avoid Setting Audio URL in itemBuilder: Setting the audio URL inside the itemBuilder causes issues because the itemBuilder function is called every time an item is built (e.g., during scrolling), which can lead to the audio resetting or playing automatically.
2- Control Play/Pause Correctly: Use state management to control the play/pause state of each audio item individually, ensuring that only one audio plays at a time.
3- Maintain State for Each Item: Utilize a reactive state management approach (Getx in this case) to maintain and update the state of each list item.

bro there is a problem i play audio but my icon not change according to index and audio not pause some times how to fix it
